# How to count mention in one day

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am try to understant how to make a table that tells me in which specific day were written the most mentions about the persons in my table.

```
SELECT
 person,
  COUNT(1) AS count_mentions,
  COUNT(DISTINCT current_date) AS mention_per_date,
FROM
  `aesthetic-honor-311413.big_data_alon_peled_2021.israel_media_person`
  GROUP BY
  person
ORDER BY
  current_date asc
LIMIT
  10;
```

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
person  mention_per_date
Tomer          24
Shalev         18
Yosef          15
Eran           15
Gal            11
(Fictive names and numbers)
```

Comment: I don't see what your query has to do with the question or desired results.  The question seems to be asking for a date, but the result is a count.

Comment: I don't understand the requirement. Can you share the (fictive) sample data that you'd like to get this result for?

Comment: can we somehow stop this most likely unintended but still SPAM!? it is same question again and again since last few days from the same class of students with slight variations! voting to close as it is ask for doing their homework!

Comment: Very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68169874/cant-remove-unwanted-data-from-a-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am try to understant how to make a table that tells me in which specific day were written the most mentions about the persons in my table.

For this question, I would expect a query like this:

```
SELECT person, date, COUNT(*)
FROM `aesthetic-honor-311413.big_data_alon_peled_2021.israel_media_person`
GROUP BY person, date
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) = 1;
```

This returns the *date* that most frequently occurs for each person.  You don't mention the name of the date column, so this just uses `date`.